# The Docker container cannot access other services on the intranet of the host company

Tags: docker, docker-compose

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  tomcat:
    image: tomcat:9
    container_name: tomcat-change
    ports:
      - "18080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "./my.war:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/my.war"
    entrypoint:
      - "catalina.sh"
      - "run"
    networks:
      - mywork

networks:
  mywork:
    name: mywork
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
      - subnet: 172.31.0.0/24
        gateway: 172.31.0.1
```

this is my docker-compose.yml

The company's LAN IP address is 172.17.xxx.xxx

My local area network IP address is 172.17.6.xxx

There is an ordinary db server in the LAN  172.17.1.xxx

I run docker compose locally The yml Docker intranet cannot connect to the database of 172.17.1.xxx

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host 172.17.1.xxx, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Ser
ver is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall
```

It is normal to start locally without using Docker

I use the window Docker Desktop

Docker version 20.10.11, build dea9396

Answer (score 1):

```
ersion: "3.7"
services:
  tomcat:
    image: tomcat:9
    container_name: tomcat-change
    ports:
      - "18080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "./my.war:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/my.war"
    entrypoint:
      - "catalina.sh"
      - "run"
    extra_hosts:
      - "db:172.17.1.xx"
```

This is all you need in the docker-compose.yml. Replace `172.17.1.xx` with the ip of your database server. In your application refer to the database host by `db`.

Comment: I added the attribute extra_hosts, but the error is the same

Comment: jdbc:sqlserver://db:1433; DatabaseName=dbPPM Is jdbc used like this

Comment: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host db, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is ru
nning on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.

Comment: can you connect with an sql client to the database from the same host where you run docker-compose?

Comment: There is no problem with the local direct running of war

Comment: login your tomcat container and try first `ping db`. that should work (you might have to install ping). After that try `telnet db 1433`. if that works, then it's the database not accepting connections from other than your host ip. If the telnet doesn't connect then maybe there is a port forwarding issue on your docker desktop. windows is a tricky thing...

Comment: I have confirmed that tomcat works normally. No need to investigate other reasons